# Finding orbit of period in dynamical system

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading my textbook and I would not able to understand about finding an orbit of period $n$.

For example; suppose $Tx = 1.8 (x-x^3)$ so it has fixed points at $ -2/3, 0,$ and $2/3$. I know how to find fixed points so I get it. But, the book said that the function has an orbit or period of 2, namely $\{+\ - \sqrt 14/3 \}$ and I don't get it and the book does not explain about it.

So I would appreciate any help to help me understand the concept of orbit and how to find or prove the orbit of a dynamical system.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve the equation $f^2(x) = x$, i.e. $ 1.8((1.8(x-x^3))-(1.8(x-x^3))^3) = x$. All fixed points are also of period $2$, so you'll find solutions to this that are fixed points too. You'll have to remove them for your set of solutions if you want points of prime period $2$.

Comment: Thanks! what is prime period 2?

Comment: The prime period of an orbit of a point $x$ under a function $f$ is the least $n$ such that $f^n(x) = x$. So here, for example, $f(\frac{\sqrt{14}}{3}) \neq \frac{\sqrt{14}}{3}$ but $f^2(\frac{\sqrt{14}}{3}) = \frac{\sqrt{14}}{3}$

Comment: Thanks! is there any difference between one period-2 orbit and an orbit of period 2?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you'll have to check with your instructor on your definitions. Some people refer only to points with orbits of prime period $2$, which do not include fixed points, when talking about orbits of period $2$ while others mean all orbits such that $f^2(x) = x$, which includes fixed points.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i got fixed points for $f^2 (x) = x$ and that are $ - 1.24722, -0.66667, 0 0.66667, $ and $ 1.247722$. Then, we exclude the first and last fixed points, Then they are points of prime period 2, and hence we get  an orbit of period 2.

Comment: What about $x=0$? That's a fixed point too but as you note, it does not have an orbit of prime period $2$.

Comment: Yeah, I forget to include that. So for instance, i want to find an orbit of period 2, i have to find $f^3 (x) =x), then find the prime points right? Thank you so much for helping me understand the concept.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23122/discussion-between-ilham-and-mathlearner).